# iOS app development: receiving notifications of new text messages

Tags: ios4, notifications, ios6, background-process, core-bluetooth

I would like to write an app that pings a Bluetooth whenever there is a new text message on my iPhone 4S. Any help on how to get started on writing the code for this app using Xcode would be very much appreciated!